# Advice on how to better ask question?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, specific-question

I'm new to SO, and I want to get some advice from experienced users over here, on how to better improve my question asking abilities? *I have seen some of the posts on how to better ask question, but would like an explanation specific to my case, so I that I can post better questions from next time.*

[Why is Angular.JS called opinionated framework? What specifics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464838/why-is-angularjs-called-an-opinionated-framework-what-specifics)

This was a question I asked, which was downvoted, and commented that it was flame inducing (which I see now, it could). So, I want to know a few things about how to better ask such type of questions?

I tried to be specific in the question, in trying to elicit answers from more advanced programmers, on *exact* implementation detail of how angular.js was forcing its own design paradigm. My intention was to see in what specific technical or conceptual way certain generalized SE principles were enforced (for example, how did angular.js manage its dependency injection from the rest of the other frameworks? or how does models get updated directly with its views - is this technique understanding good for other frameworks?) I know I should have better studied, but I am only starting out, and I would rather spend the time learning techniques or concept that can be useful across other frameworks too. Well, anyways that was the **motivation** behind asking the question.

1. Could the question be rephrased in a more appropriate manner, that wouldn't provide flame wars, and actually provide answers?
2. Is the question so bad, that it inherently doesn't have an objective answer?
3. I do see now, that such question may be better suited in a more discussive style of answers. What other place other than SO caters to such Q/A? IRCs? Other boards?
4. Would this question have a better footing in Programmer.SE?
5. How should I ask such conceptual question in future. I know they are not straight answer types of questions, but they are knowledge which I think one should gather from advanced programmers? I want to improve, and how can I do that, without violating SO community guidelines, but I see that I need to ask such questions?

Any help that explains would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is an [AngularJS Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/angular), you can try asking your question there...but you should do a search for similar questions there first, and check to see if they have a FAQ about what kind of discussions are allowed, and how to go about starting them.

Comment: I did post a comment on my original question, about why I refrained from posting into AngularJS specific groups. But I guess, I also misjudged the readership of SO, and the specific purpose SO serves. Anyways, i have now decided to stick with Ember.js. And I understood, that rephrasing would not be helpful with this type of question. I kinda wished this could be bettered with rephrasing, but @Robert pointed out, yes, it is not suitable (point no 2)

Comment: You could possibly try asking in the [JavaScript chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/17/javascript), but make sure that you [follow their guidelines](http://rlemon.github.io/so-chat-javascript-rules/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is probably not salvageable on Stack Overflow.  These kinds of questions are simply off-topic.  Stack Overflow is mostly about *software implementation...* how we can help you with your specific programming problem.

Your question may not fly on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) either.  You're basically asking us to  explain how the authors guided the development of Angular to fit their world view, and provide you with a detailed analysis.  But to do that, you already have to have prior knowledge of Angular, and if you had that knowledge, you would probably already know what "opinionated" means.

For these reasons, your question doesn't seem like it can be answerable in a few paragraphs, and it is therefore too broad.

Incidentally, a quick [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20is%20opinionated%20about%20angularjs) identified a wealth of great information that already answers your question, especially [this blog post](http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2012/12/02/angularjs-is-too-humble-to-say-youre-doing-it-wrong/).

Comment: I am asking in the Programmers Chat Room to see if your question can be migrated there.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, after reading more FAQs and meta, I think analysis are not what SO is suited for  And I am beginning to think I am getting confused over what "opinionated" means in the first place (even though, I do know what the word means). I guess, I probably need to pick one up, stick with and work over it, and then be at a better position to ask good questions. In the end, I hope any one of these modern frameworks are worth learning alone, and I do not end up feeling missed out on the other.

Comment: Will mark you answer as accepted if any further answers are not posted.

Comment: Programmers says negative.  Check out [this blog post](http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2012/12/02/angularjs-is-too-humble-to-say-youre-doing-it-wrong/); it pretty much answers your question.